Why don't we find capillary condensation all around us?
Capillary condensation is a phenomenon where condensation happens even in an unsaturated vapour provided that the radius of curvature of the condensate surface is sufficiently small, for example in capillaries.
We seem to be surrounded by a humongous number of tiny notches on rough surfaces. Is there any evidence for capillary condensation happening all around us (walls, roads, rocks, soil, etc.)? Why or why not?

Who says we don’t?

@Chemomechanics Thank you for your comment. If so, wouldn't all the water vapour be sucked out of the air and fill up all the orifices around us. In other words, every rough material would be super hygroscopic and remain moist all the time, keeping the air around it dry like a dessicant. This expectation is the basis for my assumption. However, I understand that I may be wrong, and I have edited to question to allow for both possibilities.

Water does adsorb on surfaces to reduce the free energy, preferentially so at cracks. This stops once the surface is effectively passivated; there’s no driving force for water to flow away as a liquid, creating detectable moisture and drawing water vapor from humid air to dry it indefinitely.

@Chemomechanics Thank you! Your comments and answers to many of my questions have always been enlightening and educative to me

This question is an excellent example of why physics has to be done quantitatively.
The Wikipedia article you cite gives an equation (based on the Kelvin equation) for the actual vapor pressure in the presence of a capillary:
$$\frac{P_v}{P_{sat}} = \exp\left(-\frac{2H\gamma V_l}{RT}\right)$$
where:

$P_v$ is the actual vapor pressure
$P_{sat}$ is the vapor pressure without the capillary
$H$ is the mean curvature of the meniscus, which (assuming a perfectly hydrophilic material) is $1/r$ for a hollow cylinder of radius $r$, and $1/w$ for a crack of width $w$
$\gamma$ is the surface tension, $7.2 \times 10^{-2}$ N/m for water
$V_l$ is the molar volume, $1.8 \times 10^{-5}\ \mathrm{m^3}$ for water
$R$ is the ideal gas constant, $8.3\ \mathrm{J}/(\mathrm{K \cdot mol})$
$T$ is the temperature

So suppose the temperature is 293 K and we have a 1 micron crack. Plugging in the numbers, the vapor pressure is 99.89% of the vapor pressure without the crack. So condensation will occur in this situation if the relative humidity is 99.89% or higher. By the time condensation happens in 1-micron cracks, the air would be essentially saturated anyway.
For a 10 nanometer crack (100 times smaller), the same number is 90%.
Once you get to very small capillaries, the effect does become apparent. The pore radius in silica gel is about 1 nm, which would be expected to initiate condensation at a relative humidity of 34%. And silica gel is, in fact, a dessicant.
Hopefully the small size of this effect explains why you don't actually notice it most of the time.

Thank you for an educative and enlightening answer!

To add to anon's correct answer, note that if condensation occurs within a tiny crack, then the crack fills with water and the radius of curvature of its interface to the outside world goes down, shutting down the condensation effect.
